# C++ casting a pointer to a reference to pointer of base class in function parameter

Tags: c++, pointers, pass-by-reference

I'm trying to create the constructor of a nested class, which inherits from a parent nested class, using its constructor. Basically:

```
DerivedList<T>::DerivedNested::DerivedNested(DerivedNode*& ptr)
  : BaseList<T>::BaseNested::BaseNested(ptr)
{}
```

The prototype of the constructor of my BaseNested goes like this:

```
BaseList<T>::BaseNested::BaseNested(BaseNode*& ptr)
```

(and is required to get the ptr parameter by reference since it needs the address of said pointer in its code)

I figured I had to cast my DerivedNode* to a BaseNode*, but : a static_cast::BaseNode*>(ptr) finds no matching functions since it isn't a reference, and a static_cast::BaseNode*&>(ptr) gives an invalid cast error.

The same goes for dynamic_cast. A reinterpret_cast compiles, but gives something incorrect during excecution.

Does anyone know how I could call that parent constructor?

Comment: It is not possible to have two references, one of type `DerivedNode*&` and the other of type `BaseNode*&`, refer to the same pointer. Pointers-to-pointers and references-to-pointers don't work well together with polymorphism. If you want polymorphic behavior, avoid these things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you think you need a reference, that's probably because you want to modify the pointer later. The problem is that the type of the pointer in the derived class is `DerivedNode*`, and `BaseNode*` in the base class. What if the base class affects a `DerivedNode2*` to its pointer ?

You should use setters, or move the logic from the base class to the derived ones.

Comment: I need a reference because BaseNested is required to have an attribute that is a pointer to a pointer to BaseNode (BaseNode**). That BaseNested is supposed to work like an iterator, except with one more indirection, which is why the address of that specific pointer is needed. And I'm... not sure what you mean by "move the logic"?

Comment: "Move the logic" = move the code that uses this pointer in the derived class. Probably the best you can do. Or else, use pointer to pointer, no references (but you have to be very cautious).